# Patterns and coding style to avoid using Switch statements in coding

Tags: c#, design-patterns, coding-style

Consider the code below. I want to create a `service` based on the `type` of `binding`. I have created a `switch` case for it, but I am not satisfied with the approach, I want to **avoid** `switch` statement for expandibility in future. Please suggest a better pattern or design to do this.

```
   public static object CreateBinding(string binding, object service)
   {
       switch (binding)
       {
           case "ServiceA":
               ChannelFactory<IServiceA> ServiceFactoryA = new ChannelFactory<IServiceA> (binding);
               service = ServiceFactoryA.CreateChannel();
               break;

           case "ServiceB":
               ChannelFactory<IServiceB> ServiceFactoryB = new ChannelFactory<IServiceB> (binding);
               service = ServiceFactoryB.CreateChannel();
               break;

           default:
               ChannelFactory<IServiceC> ServiceFactoryC = new ChannelFactory<IServiceC> (binding);
               service = ServiceFactoryC.CreateChannel();
               break;
       }

       OpenChannel(service);

       return service;
   }
```

Comment: There are many questions/articles on refactoring `switch` statements. It would be good idea to show what you've already tried. Indeed it is nice to get tailor-made code for your case, but that is not really goal of SO.

Comment: This is a common problem with a well documented refactoring pattern: http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html

Answer (score 4):

The most obvious method for me to remove `switch` statements is to use a `Dictionary`.

Here's how:

```
private static Dictionary<string, Func<string, object>> _bindingFactory = new Dictionary<string, Func<string, object>>()
{
    { "ServiceA", binding => new ChannelFactory<IServiceA>(binding).CreateChannel() },
    { "ServiceB", binding => new ChannelFactory<IServiceB>(binding).CreateChannel() },
    { "", binding => new ChannelFactory<IServiceC>(binding).CreateChannel() },
};

public static object CreateBinding(string binding, object service)
{
    service = _bindingFactory[_bindingFactory.ContainsKey(binding) ? binding : ""](binding);
    OpenChannel(service);
    return service;
}
```

It's slightly odd that you have `object service` as a parameter to `CreateBinding`, but I've left it as-is.

Now it is entirely possible for you to change `_bindingFactory` at run-time to produce any kind of expandability you like.